# Spinner не меняется по размеру содержимого

Tags: android, android-spinner

Поставил Spinner, загрузил в него массив через кастомный адаптер.

Теперь открываю экран, Spinner не принимает размеры и свойства item_adapter, он изначально сужает высоту отображаемого элемента.

Когда выбираешь один из элементов списка, spinner изменяется под размер этого элемента, как надо.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы spinner изначально принимал размер элемента, что используется в адаптере для этого спиннера?

Вот код на настройку Spinner:

```
public class ShopsFragment extends BaseFragment implements IUtilsAdapter, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_common_progress_bar_recycle, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    cities = SharedPreferencesManager.getCities(activity);
    if (cityPosition == -1) {
        customCityExists = true; // если есть город, который мы нашли по поиску и его не было в списке изначально
        //мы добавим его в массив первым и его же отобразим
        // а чтобы можно было найти этот кастомный город, приходится передавать не city как обычно, а location
        City customItem = new City(SharedPreferencesManager.getCityId(activity), SharedPreferencesManager.getCityName(activity));
        cities.add(0, customItem);
    }

    customAdapter = new ShopCitiesAdapter(activity, cities);
    spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    spin.setSelection(cityPosition);

    setStateLoading();
    if (shopsArrayList == null) {
        activity.getSpiceManager().execute(new ShopRequest(activity), new ShopRequestListener());
    } else setAdapter();
    return view;
}

 //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    if (firstClicked) {
        shopsArrayList = null;

        recyclerShop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setStateLoading();
        cityPosition = position;

        if (customCityExists && cityPosition == 0){
            cityOrLocation = "location";
        } else {
            cityOrLocation = "";
        }

        activity.getSpiceManager().execute(new ShopRequest(activity, cities.get(position).getId(), cityOrLocation), new ShopRequestListener());
    } else {
        firstClicked = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Это XML фрагмента:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_shop"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Код Адаптера:

```
public class ShopCitiesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
private ArrayList<City> cities;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public ShopCitiesAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<City> cities) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.cities = cities;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cities.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item_for_shop_cities, null);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_city);
    TextView cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name_of_city);
    cityName.setText(cities.get(i).getCity());
    return view;
}
}
```

Это 1 элемент адаптера:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_city"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/city" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Город" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name_of_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Первое отображение**

[image]

**Нажимаем на Spinner и выбираем элемент списка**

[image]

**После выбора элемента списка Spinner отобразился, как надо**

[image]

Comment: Ellipsize у Spinner пробовали сделать end? Раз в одну строку, чтобы обрезало текст с конца

Comment: @McDaggen пробовал ellipsize end и у спиннера, и у элемента для адаптера, он не воспринимает эти параметры, также пытался спиннеру дать свойство singleLine - не среагировал

Comment: Попробуйте в spinner добавить maxLines="2"

Comment: @McDaggen ` maxLines="2"` это не помогло. У меня же наоборот, не отображается элемент, суженный, а тот параметр просто ограничения на макс строки даёт

Comment: Может xml файл не правильно настроен? имею ввиду веса или размеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог одинаковый отступ (padding) как у самого `spinner`, так и у его итема (одного поля из массива полей `spinner`). Это решило проблему